# Things to sell vs things to be sold

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Let's look at the sentences.

These are the things to sell.

These are the things to be sold.

Which one is correct? The first one sounds good. It seems that in the first sentence we are talking about selling not the things. 
I think the second one is the omitted form of 
'These are the things that are to be sold'. We are talking about the things. In that sense the second one should be correct and appropriate.
Am I right? Plz make me understand with proper example and explanations. Which one should I use?